# How to make the exclusive or in LaTex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

Does anyone know how to make the symbol in the red box? It's the exclusive or. I've tried using detexify and looking up the symbol, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: This is not the common `xor` symbol. Should be `\oplus`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using the`\stackinset` command from the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\xor}{\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-0.15ex}{$ \vee $}{$ \bigcirc $}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ A \xor B\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \newcommand*\circledlor{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {\lor};}}

\begin{document}
  \(\circledlor\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course this will get mathord spacing and not mathbin spacing.